# How connect websocket to wss:// on https server

Tags: websocket, wss

i could connect to my websocket php server on client side js file like this:

```
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://mysite.com:9091");
```

but now we bought ssl for our  server , so url start with Https instead of Http
Now we can't connect to ws:// so i changed it to wss:// 
but still can't connect to server

```
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Comment: What server are you using. Is the server accepting tls connections and listening to the port?

Comment: server is Linux CentOs, and i could connect to server til yesterday without problem. but since yesterday we bought ssl for server .and everything stops working

Comment: @samanrad: you probably don't have SSL at port 9091 configured but at another port. Or you have configured your server wrong - look at the server side log files for any clues.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich do you mean that we have to enable ssl for 9091 port also in our server configuration ? our site already works with https

Comment: @samanrad: since you explicitly give the port number in your wss URL you have to also enable HTTPS there. wss:// is an upgrade of a https:// connection same as ws:// is an upgrade of an http:// connection.

Comment: @Steffen can you write how i have to do it ?

Comment: @samanrad: I have no idea of your setup and thus cannot provide any hints. But I'm pretty sure that you can easily find lots of information on how to setup a wss:// server properly and apply these to your specific environment. If you then still have problems please provide enough details about your setup in your question so one can actually help you.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich lets say if someone was using letsencrypt certificate, on ubuntu 18.04, amazon aws, and using virtual hosts to house the domain (among multiple domains) then how would you do it..

Comment: @DragonFire: Comments should not be used to ask new questions, even more since the original question is many years old. Please ask a real question instead with a clear problem description  and sufficient details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich first I'll try to do myself, then if a problem comes then I will post a question, but thanks for your response...